# How to transfer information on a shared iCloud account to a new individual one?

Tags: ipad, icloud, iphone

I set up an iCloud account under an old email on my iPad and I used the same iCloud account for my phone.

Now I have no storage space on either device or the iCloud accounts. How do I transfer my photos, contacts, apps, etc. from the current account on my phone to the same phone but on under a different iCloud account without losing any information?

Comment: Hint: you'll like it better if you pay the 99 cents a month for more storage and continue to use one iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real easy way to merge data from iCloud accounts. Your best bet is to contact AppleCare direct with that question.
Find your local number here: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201232